# Un-removable /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: filesystem, permissions, resolv.conf

During an upgrade to 12.04 today I've got an error when running post-install hook for `resolvconf` package:

```
Setting up resolvconf (1.63ubuntu11) ...
resolvconf.postinst: Error: Cannot replace the current /etc/resolv.conf with a symbolic link because it is immutable. To correct this problem, gain root privileges in a terminal and run 'chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf' and then 'dpkg --configure resolvconf'. Aborting.
```

Well, surely I tried running `chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf`, but `dpkg --configure resolvconf` produced the same error.

I tried to move or delete the file manually, but I can't do this even as root:

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.old 
mv: cannot move `/etc/resolv.conf' to `/etc/resolv.conf.old': Operation not permitted

sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf                                                       
rm: cannot remove `/etc/resolv.conf': Operation not permitted
```

I am able to create and then delete a file in /etc (as root), so the root partition is not mounted read-only or anything. Also:

```
lsattr /etc/resolv.conf
-----a--------- /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as per the help files (`man chattr`),

```
A  file  with the `a' attribute set can only be open in append mode for writing.
```

In your case the file has this attribute

```
The  operator  `+'  causes  the  selected attributes to be added to the
       existing attributes of the files; `-' causes them to  be  removed;
```

So the command to try would be

```
sudo chattr -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

and try listing the attributes once again using

```
lsattr /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then try deleting the file

Comment: Yep, that fixed the problem, thanks. The `chattr` manpage is kinda ambiguous - I thought it says "file can be open *only in append mode*" (i.e. no effect on other operations, such as delete), while what it actually means is "file can *only be open*, and *only in append mode*"

Answer (score 10):

For my case, is the immutable attribute of the file causing it. So do `sudo chattr -a -i /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: only this solution worked for me